# collectAsStateWithLifecycle not working with Groovy

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

My Compose project was working, until I added this in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.0-alpha05'
```

I am getting many build errors like this:

> Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in
> modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0)
> and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0
> (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)

I am also using these dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'

Lifecycle versions: 2.5.1
```

Using latest versions for for Hilt, navigation

Using:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

For Gradle plugin:

```
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
```

Any ideas?